# 3 posts in a row instead of 2 / wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme which displays blog feed in two different ways. I am using the second option (called: Small) with 2 posts in a row so the layout looks like there are two columns with posts. I would like to have three posts in a row.
This is a code responsible for a blog feed:

```
?php
    $example_i = 1; $example_ad = 0; $example_flag = true; $example_div_open = 0;
    if ( have_posts() ) { 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            /*** Mixed:  2 Small Posts, Followed by 1 Full ***/
            if($example_blog_feed_post_format == 'Mixed') { 
                if ($example_i == 1 && $example_flag) { ?><div class="row" data-fluid=".entry-title"><div class="col-md-6"><?php $example_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i = 2; $example_flag = false; ?></div><?php } 
                if ($example_i == 2 && $example_flag) { ?><div class="col-md-6"><?php $example_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i = 3; $example_flag = false; ?></div></div><?php } 
                if ($example_i == 3 && $example_flag) { $example_entry = 'full'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i=1; $example_flag = false; } 
            } 
            /*** Small: Small Image and Excerpt, 2 in a Row ***/
            else if($example_blog_feed_post_format == 'Small') {
                if($example_i%2 != 0) { $example_div_open = 1; ?><div class="row"><?php } ?>
                <div class="col-md-6"><?php $example_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i++; ?></div>
                <?php if($example_i%2 != 0) { ?></div><?php $example_div_open = 0;} ?><?php 
            }
             $example_flag = true;
        endwhile;
        if($example_i == 2 && $example_blog_feed_post_format == 'Mixed') { ?></div><?php } else if ($example_div_open == 1) { ?></div><?php }  
    } else { ?><div class="blog-feed-empty"><p><?php esc_html_e('No posts found.', 'example'); ?></p></div><?php } ?>

    </div>
```

I was trying to modify this piece of code:

```
/*** Small: Small Image and Excerpt, 2 in a Row ***/
            else if($example_blog_feed_post_format == 'Small') {
                if($example_i%2 != 0) { $example_div_open = 1; ?><div class="row"><?php } ?>
                <div class="col-md-6"><?php $example_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i++; ?></div>
                <?php if($example_i%2 != 0) { ?></div><?php $example_div_open = 0;} ?><?php 
            }
```

but with no success. 
Could someone help how should I change this code to have three posts in a row instead of two? 
I would be very grateful for help.

Edit (29 Nov): 
I tried to use the code sent me by Shital below, but it's not working. After using this solution I get:

```
<div class="blog-feed-posts">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

And my intention was to have three posts in a row. I also tried other modifications but none of them seemed to work. Could someone help me with this code?

Answer (score 0):

**add below code for 3 posts in a row.**

```
<?php
    $example_i = 1; $example_ad = 0; $example_flag = true; $example_div_open = 0;
    if ( have_posts() ) { 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            /*** Mixed:  2 Small Posts, Followed by 1 Full ***/
            if($example_blog_feed_post_format == 'Mixed') { 
                if ($example_i == 1 && $example_flag) { ?><div class="row" data-fluid=".entry-title"><div class="col-md-6"><?php $example_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i = 2; $example_flag = false; ?></div><?php } 
                if ($example_i == 2 && $example_flag) { ?><div class="col-md-6"><?php $example_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i = 3; $example_flag = false; ?></div></div><?php } 
                if ($example_i == 3 && $example_flag) { $example_entry = 'full'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i=1; $example_flag = false; } 
            } 
            /*** Small: Small Image and Excerpt, 3 in a Row ***/
            else if($example_blog_feed_post_format == 'Small') {
                if($example_i%3 != 0) { $example_div_open = 1; ?><div class="row"><?php } ?>
                <div class="col-md-4"><?php $example_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); $example_i++; ?></div>
                <?php if($example_i%3 != 0) { ?></div><?php $example_div_open = 0;} ?><?php 
            }
             $example_flag = true;
        endwhile;
        if($example_i == 2 && $example_blog_feed_post_format == 'Mixed') { ?></div><?php } else if ($example_div_open == 1) { ?></div><?php }  
    } else { ?><div class="blog-feed-empty"><p><?php esc_html_e('No posts found.', 'example'); ?></p></div><?php } ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Shital for your answer. Unfortunately it's not working properly. Now I have one post | two posts | one post | two posts in a row. Below I paste how it looks like now:

<div class="blog-feed-posts">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>